# CRM Chart filter

Tags: xml, charts, crm

I'm trying to set up a filter for a chart and used as base guideline CRM Chartguy's blog.

I want to show the Certifications of an Employee by this year and the last years, so I set up the first filter in the advanced find which looks for 'educations achieved on this year'

The chart is importing with no errors, but still shows the wrong information. I was expecting that 1 of the bars will reduce to a total number of 1, since I set up a filter to achieved on this year'

[The actual Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE2Ob.png)

[.xml of the Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeVVO.png)

Thank you for any further help.

Best Wishes

Florian